# Multiple producer/consumer and critical section code problem

Tags: c, producer-consumer, critical-section

I am attempting a multiple producer/consumer problem in C, but its not working as expected. The following is some pseudo code to represent my implementation.

```
Thread thread1;
Thread thread2;
Thread thread3;

Data data1;
Mutex data1_mutex;
Semaphore data1_empty;
Semaphore data1_fill;

Data data2;
Mutex data2_mutex;
Semaphore data2_empty;
Semaphore data2_fill;

thread1()
{
   // creates data and places it into data1.

   wait(data1_empty);
   lock(data1_mutex);

   // critical section

   unlock(data1_mutex);
   post(data1_fill);
}

thread2()
{
   // Removes data from data1, processes it, and places it into data2.

   // data1
   wait(data1_fill);
   lock(data1_mutex);

   // data2
   wait(data2_empty);
   lock(data2_mutex);

   // critical section

   // data2
   unlock(data2_mutex);
   post(data2_fill);

   // data1
   unlock(data1_mutex);
   post(data1_empty);
}

thread3()
{
   // Removes data from data2, prints its results, and removes it.

   wait(data2_fill);
   lock(data2_mutex);

   // critical section

   unlock(data2_mutex);
   post(data2_empty);
}
```

However, with this solution data1 will fill up, but thread2 will lock and never run. Is there something wrong with my implementation?

**EDIT #1**

One of the problems I found was that my second mutex was not being created correctly. I don't know what's wrong with it so I'm just using the first mutex for all threads. There is also something else I have done to get it working, so I'll update my pseudo-code to reflect this later when I have a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you post `data1_empty` and `data2_empty`  initially.

Comment: I don't think it matters.  My point is: the code you've shown does look like it's correct, provided the conditional variables are initially posted.  You can also use a debugger with threads and see where each one is stuck.

Comment: I dont have an ide or debugger at the moment. I have tried posting to both semaphores before spinning the threads, but it results in data1 setting more values than it has space for, so I don't think thats a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you use some sort of queuing type for `Data`, you should be able to remove the "empty" semaphores completely, unless you're trying to impose the condition that each `Data` queue depth is strictly 0 or 1.  If you use a local variable in `thread2`, you can reduce the size of the critical section.

The code then becomes something like this:

```
thread1() {
    //Wait for data to put in the queue (i.e. a blocking socket read)
    lock(data1_mutex);
    data1.push(someData);
    unlock(data1_mutex);
    post(data1_fill);
}

thread2() {
    DataType dataElement;
    wait(data1_fill);
    lock(data1_mutex);
    dataElement = data1.pop();
    unlock(data1_mutex);

    lock(data2_mutex);
    data2.push(dataElement);
    unlock(data2_mutex);
    post(data2_fill);
}

thread3() {
    DataType dataElement;
    wait(data2_fill);
    lock(data2_mutex);
    dataElement = data2.pop();
    unlock(data2_mutex);
    //do something with dataElement here
}
```

Comment: If .pop() makes a copy, then thread3 can unlock(data2_mutex) before using dataElement.  If it's by ref, then thread2 can't unlock data1_mutex until it has copied dataElement into data2.  (push and pop can't both be by ref, I think.)

Answer (score 0):

What wrang-wrang said, and try not to hold the lock for data_1 while you're waiting for data_2_empty.  You could achieve this by keeping an alternate buffer for data_1 and data_2 that you swap out.  Thread_2 swaps data_1 while processing it into data_2, thread_3 swaps out data_2 while processing it.  Your current pseudo-code will allow thread 1 and thread 3 to run concurrently, but it won't allow thread 2 to execute at the same time as either of the others.